# Why GADT/existential data constructors cannot be used in lazy patterns?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation, existential-type, gadt

Today, I got a compiler error when trying to use a lazy pattern when matching on an existential GADT constructor:

> An existential or GADT data constructor cannot be used inside a lazy (~) pattern

Why is that limitation? What "bad" stuff could happen, if it were allowed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Consider

```
data EQ a b where
  Refl :: EQ a a
```

If we could define

```
transport :: Eq a b -> a -> b
transport ~Refl a = a
```

then we could have

```
transport undefined :: a -> b
```

and thus acquire

```
transport undefined True = True :: Int -> Int
```

and then a crash, rather than the more graceful failure you get when trying to head-normalise the `undefined`.

GADT data represent evidence *about* types, so bogus GADT data threaten type safety. It is necessary to be strict with them to validate that evidence: you can't trust unevaluated computations in the presence of bottom.

Comment: What about existential types, rather than equality constraints? GHC doesn't allow those either -- are they also problematic?

Answer (score 12):

With "normal" data, you can skip checking the constructor during pattern-matching, on the understanding that when you try to use the data from the pattern, it might turn out to not exist, thus throwing an exception at you.

With a GADT, the *type signature* potentially changes depending on which constructor is present. We need to know about types at *compile-time*; it's no good not checking the constructor until you need the values. If you do, you might have a type mismatch error. And that, potentially, means your program crashing with a segmentation fault (or worse). Haskell programs should *never* segfault.